# Crear una vista en sql que recopile datos de empleado y sueldo

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Estoy haciendo un trabajo para la escuela, en que me piden que haga una vista que recopile los siguientes datos:

ID del empleado, nombre y apellidos, salario del mismo, salario máximo y % del salario actual respecto al máximo (esto último no lo entiendo muy bien)

He decidido ir por partes y antes de crear la vista, he querido hacer la select correspondiente. He llegado hasta aquí:

```
select EMPLOYEE_ID, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, SALARY, max(SALARY), SALARY % max(salary) 
from EMPLOYEES 
group by EMPLOYEE_ID;
```

Evidentemente faltarían los identificadores, pero el sql developer me tira el siguiente error:

> ORA-00911: invalid character
>   00911. 00000 -  "invalid character"
>   *Cause:    identifiers may not start with any ASCII character other than
>              letters and numbers.  $#_ are also allowed after the first
>              character.  Identifiers enclosed by doublequotes may contain
>              any character other than a doublequote.  Alternative quotes
>              (q'#...#') cannot use spaces, tabs, or carriage returns as
>              delimiters.  For all other contexts, consult the SQL Language
>              Reference Manual.
>   *Action: Error en la línea: 1, columna: 72

No entiendo por qué, ya que no tengo identificadores en ninguna parte... Los he tenido, pero los he ido quitando para descartar errores, pero antes de este error me tiraba un error sobre temas de agrupar datos, el cual no soy capaz de recuperar ya que sólo me tira este ahora...

Mi pregunta es:

> Cómo puedo solucionar el error que me tira? Y también me gustaría
>   saber si mi consulta está bien hecha, en caso de que no, me gustaría
>   que alguien me pudiera decir cómo seria la forma correcta de hacerla,
>   ya que tengo un pelín olvidado el tema de BD, aunque con un breve
>   refresco podré sacarlo.

Answer (score 0):

Esta parte es la que está incorrecta:

```
SALARY % max(salary)
```

La sinaxis es `CAMPO o (funcion)` `<espacio o as >` `ALIAS`. Por ejemplo:

```
max(salary) salario_maximo
```

o

```
max(salary) as salario_maximo
```

Te recomiendo usar "pje" en lugar del simbolo "%" en los nombres de los campos. % tiene un significado propio en sql y puede volverse un problema en algun momento.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que logro entender es que lo buscado es: Obtener el salario de todos los empleados y la relación en porcentaje con el salario más alto de todos los empleados.

Bien, esto significa que tienes que construir al menos dos consultas independientes, una para obtener todos los empleados y sus salarios y otra para obtener el salario máximo.

Puedes hacerlo de muchas formas, la más rápida es integrara ambas de la siguiente forma:

```
SELECT  EMPLOYEE_ID, 
        FIRST_NAME, 
        LAST_NAME, 
        SALARY,
        SALARY / (SELECT MAX(SALARY) FROM EMPLOYEES) * 100
        FROM EMPLOYEES 
        GROUP by EMPLOYEE_ID;
```

Con `(SELECT MAX(SALARY) FROM EMPLOYEES)` obtienes el salario más alto de todos y luego aplicándolo a cada `SALARY` obtienes el porcentaje que representa del mayor.